# How can I solve a "CreateBuilder" problem?

Tags: .net, webapi

Just been going through the API side of my final project, and in the "Program.cs" file, there appears to be a red squiggly line underneath the 'CreateBuilder" bit of the code. I want help, please! Here's the code:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplicationBuilder.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.

        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        object value = builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyWebApiContext>(opt =>
        opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("MyWebAPIContext"));
       //builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
       //{
       //c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });

       var app = builder.Build();

       // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
       if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
       {
           app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

           app.UseDefaultFiles();
           app.UseStaticFiles();

           app.UseHttpsRedirection();

           app.UseAuthorization();

           app.MapControllers();

           app.Run();
       }
    }
}
```

and the error message, is, as follows:
error CS0117: 'WebApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'CreateBuilder'.
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should implements a IHostBuilder interface in your Program.cs.

The host is configured, created and executed in the Program class in the Main() method where the CreateHostBuilder method is called to create and configure a builder object that calls the Build and Run methods:

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

After you can call it inside your Main method

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
```

Everthing inside your Program { } class.

[look here](https://sahansera.dev/dotnet-core-generic-host/) for more details.

Hope this helps